# Meteor.js and hardware requirements. What about productivity?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is Meteor.js high-load framework for server? All this reactivity seems to be very exacting.

Comment: This is too broad a question. Like any other framework/ecosystem, a barebones install has negligible load on a system, whereas the actual work that it is programmed by the coder begins introducing the load. All the while, there are infinite number of answers to your question, depending on the what kind of app you will be building and with how much data, updates, visitors, concurrent users etc. Please google combinations of keywords such as "meteor performance scalability load profile" etc as well as read through blogs, discussion groups, and of course the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It does not require much CPU/RAM. I have my instances running on Digital Ocean with 512MB - DO has SSDs, you might want to add a swap file.

W.r.t reactivity, there are best practices (hint: oplog) to enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor aims to a fast framework to develop your applications. It is possible to scale Meteor application but, usually, the bottleneck in scaling any application is the architecture. Getting things right in a reactive paradigm requires time, it's very easy to screw it up. Today in production, we've application that are not efficient client side because of recalculations, the same happens in the server. Nesting autoruns (Tracker.autorun) is hard to right at first.

In my opinion, there are better solution if performance is key for you. Although many developers and bloggers claim that Meteor is fast, Mongodb is fast, Node js is fast, bla bla bla. It's not that fast, it's just convenient in the beginning but in long run you're going to face architectural problems and need to refactor your application in order to scale it.

It really depends on what high-load means to your. If you want to perform calculations, Meteor is not for you neither NodeJs. For an initial prototype/applications, Meteor is a great match.